# Appending email to individual words in a string

Tags: powershell

The CSV looks like this: *cat .\email.csv*

```
TheName
"Adam,  Bertram,  Joe,  Jones,  Mary,  Baker"
```

I'm trying to create an output that will list the name and their email address in the output.  However, the cell that contains the names, is all in one line with comma separation in the cell instead of each field.  I'm sure it's easy, but for some reason, my head isn't able to easily do this.  UGH!  Here is my attempt.  It shouldn't be complicated, right?  This is a rapidly evolving CSV and I'm unable to change that output.  Hopefully someone might have a quick fix for me?    TIA!

```
$NEWtmpName = @()
$emailLIST = import-csv -path email.csv
$emailLIST | foreach-object {

   $tmpName = $($_.TheName)
   write-host -f yellow $tmpName + "s email is" + $tmpName + "@microsoft.com"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$emailList = Import-CSV .\email.csv
foreach($entry in $emailList)
{
    foreach($name in $entry.TheName.Split(','))
    {
        Write-Host -f Yellow "$($name)'s email is $($name)@microsoft.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: OOOHH!  I believe this is money!  Thank you.  On a side note, I'm finding that it's putting a blank space before the user's on subsequent lines.  I'll play around with the output, but at least now it's cycling thru the names correctly and putting in our email!  Thank you!

Comment: .Trim()

WOOT!  Thanks again, @LordPupazz

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-replace` regex operator to append the domain suffix to the end of each individual word in the input string:

```
Import-Csv email.csv |ForEach-Object {
  $_.TheName = $_.TheName -replace '(?<=\w\b)','@microsoft.com'
  $_
} |Export-Csv email_fixed.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This created another file instead of working with the information.  I appreciate the response, however.